# how to get web-mode to ignore alignment in favor of indentation during method chaining?

Tags: indentation, web-mode, align

when I write code (Javascript, specifically) in a web-mode buffer which chains methods across newlines:

```
object.foo()
.bar()
```

web-mode seems to want to align it like this:

```
object.foo()
      .bar()// hitting enter here will dot-align my code
```

how can I get it to ignore alignment in this case and instead perform  javascript-mode style indentation like this:

```
object.foo()
    .bar()// adding the closing paren here will indent code by four spaces
```

?  `web-mode-code-indent-offset` is set to 4, which works in all other cases like functions and other blocks, but not here, and nothing else in `M-x customize-group web-mode` seemed immediately applicable.

I'm using Emacs 26.0 and web-mode 20170131.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ah, turns out it's the `web-mode-indentation-params` list:

`(add-to-list '(web-mode-indentation-params) '("lineup-calls" . nil))`